# Which coding language to use for very large datasets?

Tags: python, r, bigdata, matlab, programming

I have a very large panel data set (contains around 50M observations, size around 3G). I would to run an algorithm on it. The algorithm basically just loops over observations. Ideally, I would like to use functions in numpy, but I guess this would be really slow. Would R or matlab be good for this? Are there any other python packages I could use?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have small data so don't use a cluster (but multi-core is fine). Just pay attention to your algorithm's complexity. Vectorize where possible, avoiding loops.

Comment: Why do you think numpy arrays are slow? Have you found a situation where they could be significantly faster? If performance is a concern, there's also Julia.

Answer (score 1):

Python is highly efficient for large scale datasets.
Second choince will be R.

Try python scikit-learn if you want to solve a machine learning problem.
Pandas for manipulating and extracting data.

Comment: And make sure you have high RAM. Use EC2 or google cloud free trial. Google gives you upto 52GB RAM for free.